# Including a PHP class file only once

Tags: php, class, calling-convention

I'm using methods from a PHP class all over my code and I don't want to do "require_once" in every file I'm using that class. Is there a way to include the class in a single file, and then access it from everywhere in the code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here ya go
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: I don't know how helpful it is to replace a single require_once statement in each file with an autoload function.

Comment: This is where the SPL autoloader comes in handy ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use the auto_prepend_file directive (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php), which you should be able to set via .htaccess if you have no other method of doing so.